# How to properly use OpenMP for this nested loop (Fortran)

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have recently started to parallelize a serial code I've been developing and was curious if anyone had input on how to properly apply OpenMP for these loops.

```
 F_vol = 0.0_bp 
 G_vol = 0.0_bp 
 H_vol = 0.0_bp 
 RHS_vol = 0.0_bp 

 !$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(e,i1,j1,F,G,H) 
 DO e=1,NE 
     DO i1=1,Np 
         DO j1=1,NPTS
             CALL Flux(Q(j1,e,:),F,G,H)
            
             F_Vol(i1,e,:) = F_Vol(i1,e,:) + Stuff(j1)*F(:)
             G_Vol(i1,e,:) = G_vol(i1,e,:) + Stuff(j1)*G(:)
             H_Vol(i1,e,:) = H_vol(i1,e,:) + Stuff(j1)*H(:)
            END DO 
     END DO 
 END DO 
 !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

As a note, the arrays, F, G, and H are of size 5 and are temporary arrays.  Additionally, F_Vol,G_Vol,H_Vol is of dimension (NE,Np,5)  The part I am unsure on is, how to properly parallelize the arrays I sum from j1=1,NPTS. Given that they are not dependent on each other but vary between i1,e, I think using PRIVATE() is required. as to avoid overwriting.  Lastly, I am fixated on these loops as according to GProf, a good portion of my computational expense is in this area of code.

Comment: AFAIK, le last array dimension is the least contiguous in memory so it should be much better to transpose your array first or even swap the indices regarding the other algorithm access pattern. Alternatively, you can store the value of F/G/H in a temporary array to avoid uncontiguous accesses. The problem with the current memory access is that it will use a lot more memory throughput than needed and thus the parallel implementation will probably not scale well and the sequential implementation is not efficient.

Comment: It would help if you could clarify what you mean by "properly apply OpenMP" - it could either mean "I am getting the wrong answer" or "I am getting the right answer, but it is slow/not scaling well". Looking at your code I suspect the latter but as I say to confirm this would be useful. And iff it is this some performance figures and why you are worried would be better, best would be a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I usually have the best success getting the SIMD side working first. As previously mentioned, the Index/loop order looks problematic. If some reordering removes compute time, then one can see if parallelisation helps later. There are vector reports with someone compilers, that can be a great help here.